# Uninstalling Crossover return an error, How to fix it?

Tags: crossover

on executing command `sudo apt remove crossover` following error returned

```
    Removing crossover (20.0.4-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/crossover.prerm: 47: /opt/cxoffice/bin/cxtie: not found
dpkg: error processing package crossover (--remove):
 installed crossover package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit s
tatus 127
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 crossover
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then recreate missed files by

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/cxoffice/bin/
sudo touch /opt/cxoffice/bin/cxtie
sudo chmod a+x /opt/cxoffice/bin/cxtie
```

and then remove the application as usual

```
sudo apt remove crossover
```

Note: better method is to install CrossOver again using its `crossover_20.0.4-1.deb` package and then remove it again.

Comment: thank you for the comment, on using `sudo dpkg -P --force-all crossover` it still gives the following error `Removing crossover (20.0.4-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/crossover.prerm: 47: /opt/cxoffice/bin/cxtie: not found
dpkg: error processing package crossover (--purge):
 installed crossover package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 crossover`

Comment: Then lets create this files manually by `sudo mkdir -P /opt/cxoffice/bin/; sudo touch /opt/cxoffice/bin/cxtie` and retry above command.

Comment: it returns following error `sudo dpkg -P --force-all crossover
(Reading database ... 295210 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing crossover (20.0.4-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/crossover.prerm: 47: /opt/cxoffice/bin/cxtie: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package crossover (--purge):
 installed crossover package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
 crossover`

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you dear @n0rbert it is removed from the system, Best regards

Comment: Great! So you can accept this answer using checkmark on the left of it.

Comment: Thank you for helping out @n0rbert